# How to build an object TYPE with boolean values, but at least one has to be true

Tags: typescript, types

I want to make sure that both AgeDivisions and EventStyles has at least one true value.

### Here are my types:

```js
type AgeDivisions = {
  youth: boolean;
  middleSchool: boolean;
  highSchool: boolean;
  college: boolean;
  open: boolean;
};

type EventStyles = {
  folkstyle: boolean;
  freestyle: boolean;
  grecoRoman: boolean;
  jello: boolean;
  noGiJits: boolean;
  giJits: boolean;
  judo: boolean;
  beach: boolean;
};

type EventInfo = {
  name: string;
  venueName: string;
  address: string;
  date: string;
  subTitle: string;
  country: string;
  eventType: EventType;
  hasGirlsOnlyDivision: boolean;
  link: string;
  ageDivisions: AgeDivisions;
  eventStyles: EventStyles;
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
  description: string;
};
```

> I imagine the way to achieve this is by making a generic type that I will pass AgeDivisions and EventStyles to. However, it might be easier to just make a new type for each of them respectfully

Comment: The idea with the generic function that will check it is the best option here. Creating a type with all variations is going to explode the compiler

Comment: @wonderflame do you know how to do it? I can't figure it out.

Comment: @wonderflame I don't think the compiler would explode since it should end up with a union that scales linearly with the number of properties.  Maybe the work goes with, like, the square of the number of properties, but that's still reasonable unless the object has a thousand properties or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own utility type `AtLeastOneTrue<K>` that takes a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of key types `K` and produces a union where each member has all-`boolean` properties except for one which can only be `true`.  This will allow more than one to be `true` but prohibit them all being `false`.  Here's one way to make that type:

```
type AtLeastOneTrue<K extends string> = 
  { [P in K]: { [Q in K]: Q extends P ? true : boolean } }[K]
```

That's essentially a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).  If you have a union of key-like types `K` which evaluates to `K1 | K2 | K3`, and you want to convert that into `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`, you can use a distributive object type of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`.  This creates a new object type and immediately indexes into it, producing a union of its properties.  So the output is not an object (well, unless `F<P>` makes objects).

Anyway our inner operation `F<P>` is `{[Q in K]: Q extends P ? true : boolean}`.  The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `Q extends P ? true : boolean` is responsible for producing `boolean` properties for every key except the one we're focused on, which will be `true`.

---

Let's see what it does with `AgeDivisions`:

```
type AgeDivisions = AtLeastOneTrue<
  "youth" | "middleSchool" | "highSchool" | "college" | "open"
>;

/* type AgeDivisions = {
    youth: true;
    middleSchool: boolean;
    highSchool: boolean;
    college: boolean;
    open: boolean;
} | {
    youth: boolean;
    middleSchool: true;
    highSchool: boolean;
    college: boolean;
    open: boolean;
} | { ⋯        
    highSchool: true;        
⋯ } | { ⋯
    college: true;       
⋯ } | {
    youth: boolean;
    middleSchool: boolean;
    highSchool: boolean;
    college: boolean;
    open: true;
} */
```

And make sure that it behaves as desired:

```
let a: AgeDivisions;
a = { college: false, highSchool: false, middleSchool: true, 
  open: false, youth: false }; // okay
a = { college: true, highSchool: false, middleSchool: false, 
  open: true, youth: false }; // okay
a = { college: false, highSchool: false, middleSchool: false, 
  open: false, youth: false }; // error
```

Looks good!  So you can then define `EventStyles` like

```
type EventStyles = AtLeastOneTrue<
  "folkstyle" | "freestyle" | "grecoRoman" | "jello" | 
  "noGiJits" | "giJits" | "judo" | "beach"
>;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsAyECGBnYB5AdhAKgJwFcIAeAaSggA9gJMATFKNPAS0wHMA+KAXigG8oAbQAKUNlFIBdAFwDhARXGZJsqEqo16jMQH4owQtDkAjAPZmANshUBfKLaHSAsACg3oSLHYQAIiwA3FhQWM0xGPjhEVAxsfCJiACIQMwJgAAtEqAAfKESAWxY6OmsAZQBjdItLLNzE9JZ2dIqqq1q88qtrH3bEs0hMRM43AHoAKgNwaBgffyCQsIiBNyhVqBS09LlDIgBuFbXC4rLK6tNqm33XNagGppazqHMrS4PVzstuiHOXpEwrm79Wg-ax-K72XL8N7rVIZEGva6HIolCAPKzbIwAtZ3ZqndFPC5g6EfL7womI1ZAzBk-5uCHLCkwzY0rGrI4otGWFnQnGcjF7YldCA+bmMqmi+lQxkbOEE360xnsk6tLly0EKm68vGq57q1lQEnC74GTHQ8VqhGS6EyrYW8k3JWo7WizWNXEql1rQ0iu0atbmnYQcFQMYjNxuazAKBIOQzPyBYKhcJXJC8eTe40AMyQlhQEAANLc3XyoNncwWoI6S4HC+ay3nCza5PXoLZdlARiMoGYANZIEBuVN8QQZ-kVrUe0s5huV5HKx4t2sDMeN2G2lsOdud7t9geuIfpoU+xdF+7OqflwtV88nuvTitNi95zcdrsQPB4Mx4cPuX+eaAAKIBLQwClKA1hLFEyBoFguBGEkmZWD2aAgNYvSZngEAQChaE5Hk7CYZ0ABKZj5H8vQAFYQJ8Zi9JgZgAOIsAAUiwwAoL07AsWxHF4YkFEEHQtF8SYyCVEMP4-v+UBASBACSmCIWmUqrJgSD5MazBsOwWLAZgRAAHLqZphjaViSDFJhKAoHIWkcFidBIDQtmmfZBwoAQJg4Gx1guawbmIp0BCYIYIB+WZBwQHpwA4FM4X2a+BqkdAYQHOkqBMXguZYJYIBzImYSepYbA9vFOkHEgswJgs4SxlV8xJigWJRSBYGodhciySFbUQVilhOWxgkmf55WIpYYRccAQ1lQ52HlKwYDAEmM10rsQA)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I don't get why there are two objects in our type definition?

Comment: It's a distributive object type; the outer `{ [P in K]:  F<P> }[K]` operation computes the union of `F<P>` for every member of `P`.  It's linked in ms/TS#47109  I've edited my answer to explain that part more.